# How to get Spring to match enums when capitalization does not match?

Tags: spring, kotlin

I had this enum:

```
enum class CallbackStatus{  success, failed }
```

Due to `ktlint` complaining about the lower-cased names, I converted them to upper-case like this:

```
enum class CallbackStatus{  SUCCESS, FAILED }
```

This made several tests fail with errors such as

```
Failed to convert from type [java.lang.String] to type [@org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable no.posten.push.notification.CallbackStatus] for value 'failed'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No enum constant mypackage.CallbackStatus.failed
```

This is used in a endpoint declaration:

```
 @PostMapping("{status}")
  fun handleCallback(
    @PathVariable callbackReference: String,
    @PathVariable status: CallbackStatus,
    @RequestBody callback: Callback,
    @RequestHeader(notificationEngineCallbackHeader) callbackSecret: String,
  ): ResponseEntity<Any> =
```

So my basic concern is trying to get Spring to recognize that the string "failed" should automatically be serialized to an enum `CallbackStatus.FAILED`.

After some digging, I figured out that it's Spring's `StringToEnumConverterFactory` that does `Enum.valueOf(string)`. I guess I would need to override this?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom method that will convert `String` value to `ENUM` constant:

```
public enum  CallbackStatus{
  SUCCESS("success"),
  FAILED("failed");

  private final String value;

  CallbackStatus(String value) {
    this.value = value;
  }

  public static CallbackStatus fromValue(String value) {
    for (CallbackStatus status : values()) {
      if (status.value.equalsIgnoreCase(value)) {
        return status;
      }
    }
    throw new IllegalArgumentException(
        "Unknown enum CallbackStatus " + value + ", Allowed values are " + Arrays
            .toString(values()));
  }
}
```

And when you are going to set `ENUM` value from `String` it will be something like this:

```
CallbackStatus status = CallbackStatus.fromValue("success");
```

Comment: That won't work with the shown Spring endpoint. It is Spring that does the deserialization, not me, so I would need to provide a custom converter factory, as mentioned. Like this https://www.baeldung.com/spring-type-conversions

Comment: agree and in convertor you can invoke `CallbackStatus.fromValue()` method that i wrote in answer, something like here you will have [spring-enum-request-param](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-enum-request-param) I think